# Resource file gets included twice in Mac OS X application package built using CMake and CPack

Tags: cmake, cpack

I am trying to use CMake and CPack to build and package a Mac OS X application, but I can't figure out the correct way to include resources.

This is what my `CMakeLists.txt` looks like:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(foo)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(foo foo.c foo.txt)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(foo PROPERTIES MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(foo PROPERTIES RESOURCE foo.txt)
INSTALL(TARGETS foo DESTINATION ".")
SET(CPACK_GENERATOR TGZ)
INCLUDE(CPack)
```

However, when I use it to build a package, `foo.txt` gets included twice: in the `Resources` directory of the bundle as expected, but also at the root:

```
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
$ make package
$ tar -xvzf foo-0.1.1-Darwin.tar.gz 
x foo-0.1.1-Darwin/foo.app/Contents/Info.plist
x foo-0.1.1-Darwin/foo.app/Contents/MacOS/foo
x foo-0.1.1-Darwin/foo.app/Contents/Resources/foo.txt
x foo-0.1.1-Darwin/foo.txt
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

For easier reading, here is what the final, working, `CMakeLists.txt` looks like (as per Josh's answer and my comment on it):

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(foo)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(foo foo.c foo.txt)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(foo PROPERTIES MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE)
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(foo.txt PROPERTIES MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION Resources)
INSTALL(TARGETS foo DESTINATION ".")
SET(CPACK_GENERATOR TGZ)
INCLUDE(CPack)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the line `* PROPERTIES RESOURCE foo.txt)` should solve the problem.

Since you have included cpack in your cmake file, the generated TGZ will contain all of the files which would be installed with `make install`. In this case, you have

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(foo PROPERTIES MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE)
```

which will build `foo` as an OS X application bundle ([doc)](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#prop_tgt%3aMACOSX_BUNDLE), and

```
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(foo PROPERTIES RESOURCE TRUE)
```

specifies foo.txt as a resource files ([doc](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#prop_tgt%3aRESOURCE)).  With both of those PROPERTIES set, `make install` will create two versions of foo.txt. One in the bundle, `foo.app/Contents/Resources/foot.txt`, and one in the top level directory, `foo.txt`.  Therefore, CPack will also generate those two versions of foo.txt.

Comment: Actually, that worked a little too well. Removing that line caused `foo.txt` to not get included at all, neither in the `Resources` folder nor at the root. However, replacing it with the line `SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(foo.txt PROPERTIES MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION Resources)` had the desired effect.